# org.apache.commons.cli CommandLineParser isn't keeping the passed arguments

Tags: java

When I pass arguments to my program to be parsed by the CommandLineParser, it doesn't take my arguments from passed to the main method.

The code:

```
public class Main {
private static final Option ARG_HELP = new Option("h", "help", false, "HELP - Prints command line arguments and their uses");
private static final Option ARG_SERVER = new Option("s", "server", true, "SERVER_URL - Full HTTP(s) url of the server");
private static final Option ARG_USER = new Option("u", "user", true, "USERNAME - Username used for authentication");
private static final Option ARG_PASSWORD = new Option("p", "password", true, "PASSWORD - Password used for authentication");
private static final Option ARG_TARGET = new Option("t", "target", true, "TARGET_DIR - Base directory used for pushing or pulling files");
private static final Option ARG_PUSH = new Option("push", "push", false, "PUSH - Push xml config to server");
private static final Option ARG_PULL = new Option("pull", "pull", false, "PULL - pull xml config from server");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CommandLineParser clp = new DefaultParser();
    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption(ARG_HELP);
    options.addOption(ARG_SERVER);
    options.addOption(ARG_USER);
    options.addOption(ARG_PASSWORD);
    options.addOption(ARG_TARGET);
    options.addOption(ARG_PUSH);
    options.addOption(ARG_PULL);

    try{
        CommandLine cl = clp.parse(options, args);

        if(cl.getArgList().size() < 5){
           ArrayList<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>(cl.getArgList());
        }
        else{
            printHelp(options);
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint at the if statement and check my cl object, the args are 0. But when I look at args passed in the clp.parse(options, args) method they're the arguments that I passed when I ran the program.

Example arguments passed: -s https://localhost:8443 -u admin -p admin -t C:\users\admin -pull

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct behaviour.

According to [the `CommandLine.getArgList()` JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#getArgList--):

> Retrieve any left-over non-recognized options and arguments

Since all the arguments from your command line are recognized as options and arguments there are no left-over arguments.

Comment: But the cl object itself doesn't keep the args either. When setting a breakpoint and looking into the object the args are 0